# Google Assistant "Error: no such option: --project-id" error

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant, google-assist-api

Google Assistant "Error: no such option: --project-id" error while installing google assistant

```
/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py:163: UserWarning: Global variable 'stderr' in cdef(): for consistency with C it should have a storage class specifier (usually 'extern')
  warnings.warn("Global variable '%s' in cdef(): for consistency "
/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py:163: UserWarning: Global variable '__stderrp' in cdef(): for consistency with C it should have a storage class specifier (usually 'extern')
  warnings.warn("Global variable '%s' in cdef(): for consistency "
Error: no such option: --project-id
```

```
googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id my-dev-project --device-model-id my-model
```

I ran the code but got the error

I can't find what is the problem please help